# Android ORMLite add annotations to library model

Tags: java, android, annotations, ormlite

I am using ORMLite in android. I have a library which provides me with a POJO which has certain fields (name, id, description) but it is not annotated with the ORMLite annotations.

Is there a way to use ORMLite to store this model in my db without actually modifying the library model directly. Can i use a wrapper object somehow as an adapter?

```
public class Asset {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I can specify a config file which will describe each field and use that in the Database Helper.

Here is the reference link. Works perfectly!

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/fieldConfig/FieldConfigMain.java

Comment: you cannot mark it until 2 days have passed. Thanks for the reminder